# Remove anything not being an int from a tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

So for example I get an

```
a = 1, 4, "a", 3, "bcd", 4,
>>> a
(1, 4, 'a', 3, 'bcd', 4)
```

and I want it to become

```
>>> a
(1, 4, 3, 4)
```

How can I do it?

I'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to produce a new tuple. You can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) and [`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) to produce it:

```
a = tuple(v for v in a if isinstance(v, int))
```

This filters on an [`isinstance()` test](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to see if the value is an integer.

Demo:

```
>>> a = (1, 4, 'a', 3, 'bcd', 4)
>>> tuple(v for v in a if isinstance(v, int))
(1, 4, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Could you explain a little about this code? I started learning python just 2 days ago and stuff like this still seems like black magic to me. Thanks.

Comment: @ca1ek: I linked you to the tutorial on generator expressions, as well as the documentation for every function used. The `for v in a` part is just a loop; if an element in the loop passes the `if isinstance(v, int)` test, it is included in the tuple.

Comment: @ca1ek: the tutorial explains generator expressions in terms of [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), explained a little earlier in the same tutorial.